# Parsing errors appear randomly and temporarily

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a small react app and every so often after I save a file, the code won't compile due to some parsing error on a line that I didn't change and had not been previously problematic. A workaround I have found is to delete a random semicolon, save, put the semicolon back and save again which then allows my app to recompile without issue.

I've pasted some code below that now apparently has errors. I've also pasted an image of my error message in the browser. Seems to be related to my destructuring perhaps?

I have tried running `npm install` again but that didn't solve the issue. I am running `node version v6.11.3` and `react version 16.7.0,`

I would like to solve this mysterious issue -- has anyone else have this happen to them?

```
  maybeRenderCalendar() {
    const { openCalendar } = this.state;

    if (!openCalendar) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <Calendar />
    );

  }
```

[image: Browser error]

Comment: Random idea, try saving your code via a different editor, and see if the problem still reoccurs?

Comment: What's doing the compilation? Webpack dev server?

Comment: @rayhatfield not sure -- I started this app using `create-react-app`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you -- I had been using vs code and switched over to Sublime to test this. So far there are no issues in Sublime. Given that information, I wonder if it's a linting bug or something? Not sure how to troubleshoot this.